# window.location in jquery file in objective-c showing jquery file location instead of window.location argument

Tags: jquery, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

In the jQuery file itself:

```
this.item_test = function(){
    $('body').css('background-color', '#00ff00');
    window.location = "/allCorrect/yes";
}
```

**Out come 1 (for line 1 proves jQuery is working):** The background of the `UIWebView` colors green (expected & correct).

**Out come 2 (for line 2, the window.location line):** In the `(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:` delegate method, the expected value for `request.mainDocumentURL.relativePath` is `/allCorrect/yes`.

My Problem:
Instead of getting "/allCorrect/yes", I get the below file location of the calling jQuery file itself:

"/Users/chiemekailo/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/77BB3C4A-E99C-47C3-B2AE-F4DSDMFE84MFOEF/Documents/Unzipped/OPS"

Comment: Hi Akeem. It's not very clear what your question is. Can you clarify outcome 1 and 2 and also explain what you mean in `//Instead I get the location of the calling jquery file itself as in below:`?  Please don't do this in the comments either. Instead, use the **edit** link under the question to edit the question body.

Comment: Thanks @jmort253. I have updated question, and will move on to accept any good answers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work without using jQuery so I can't imagine why or how jQuery makes a difference, but instead of using a location change you could try this method instead which (without jQuery) will also trigger webViewShouldStartLoadWithRequest to see if it works with jQuery.

```
iFrame = document.createElement("IFRAME");
iFrame.setAttribute("src", "/allcorrect/yes");
document.body.appendChild(iFrame); 
iFrame.parentNode.removeChild(iFrame);
iFrame = null;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Martin. I am using jQuery for other purposes, just happened that the obvious document.location of JavaScript was not working. When I resumed programming at a later time, it was working.

Comment: Your answer is good & will be useful in other areas; hence I'll mark it as answer.

Comment: If this still doesn't work with jQuery then yet another way of jumping into Objective-C from Javascript is using a form submission.